# Distance inequalities in topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Prove that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we have
 $$d_\infty(x, y) \le  d_2(x, y) \le  d_1(x, y) ≤ 2 d_2(x, y) ≤ 2 d_\infty(x, y)$$

Any hint please ?

Comment: There must be something wrong there. Notice that if $d_{\infty}(x,y) \leq d_2(x,y)$ and $2d_2(x,y) \leq 2d_{\infty}(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then $d_2=d_{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1):

For these inequalities it helps to square them, to get rid of the root in $d_2$, and use that for positive numbers $a \le b$ iff $\sqrt{a} \le \sqrt{b}$ iff $a^2 \le b^2$:

$d^2(x,y)^2 = (x_1-y_1)^2 + (x_2- y_2)^2 \le 2d_\infty(x,y)^2$, as both terms $|x_i-y_i|$ can be estimated above by $d_\infty(x,y)$.
So taking the root gives $d_2(x,y) \le \sqrt{2}d_\infty(x,y)$.

Also $d_1(x,y) = |x_1 - y_1| + |x_2 - y_2| \le 2d_\infty(x,y)$ in the same way.

$d^2_\infty(x,y)$ equals one of $|x_i-y_i|^2 = (x_i -y_i)^2$ ($i=1$ or $i=2$) the other squared term only possibly adds more so: $d_\infty^2(x,y) \le d_2^2(x,y)$ and taking the root we get $d_\infty(x,y) \le d_2(x,y)$.

$d_1^2(x,y) = (|x_1 - y_1|^2 + 2|x_1-y_1||x_2-y_2| + |x_2 -y_2|^2) \ge d_2^2(x,y)$ so again: $d_2(x,y) \le d_1(x,y)$ etc.

That $d_\infty(x,y) \le d_1(x,y)$ is trivial: the maximum is at most the sum of both (the maximal value is part of the sum and all terms are positive).

Also we can estimate $d_1(x,y)$ by twice the maximal value, so $d_1(x,y) \le 2d_\infty(x,y)$.

So I get $$d_\infty \le d_1 \le d_2 \le \sqrt{2}d_\infty \le \sqrt{2}d_1$$